# Nested Update in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie to Mongodb and doing self-learning by going through Mongodb documentation. I am struggling with the following scenario, please suggest me how to achieve this in Mongodb:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2d123456"),
    "Name" : "MongoDB",
    "BookCode" : "ID321",
    "Issue" : [
        {
            "Name" : "ABC",
            "Date" : '2016-12-15'
        },
        {
            "Name" : "DEF",
            "Date" : '2017-10-01'
        }
    ]
}
```

My Scenario is:
- If there is a document with particular Name & BookCode then check if there is any Issue.Name with same name exists or not, if exists then update else insert new array under Issue.

```
if exists (Name: 'abc' and BookCode: 'book1')
    then if exists (Issue.Name: 'DEF')
        then
            Update Issue.Date
        else
            Insert
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: you are trying this on mongo shell or via some code ?

Comment: trying on mongo shell

Comment: @sidgate still not able to find how to combine if exists..then..if exists thing in mongo query

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this:

```
db.Books.find({Name:"MongoDB", BookCode:"ID321"}).forEach( function (thisIssue)
{
    thisIssue.Issue.forEach(function (item)
    {
       if(item.Name === 'ABC') 
       {
            item.Date = "201705011315.0"
        }
            db.Books.save(thisIssue);
       }
     });
});
```

Working till some extend.
Is this can be possible using UPSERT??
I tried upsert (with unique index on Name, BookCode & Item.Name) but it inserting new subdocument under Items.